# mysql startup error '--safe-show-database' 160628 11:50:37 [ERROR]

Tags: mysql

On checking error log of /var/log/mysql/error.log, I see this:

```
160628 11:50:37 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--safe-show-database'
160628 11:50:37 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by commenting out a few lines for safe mode in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

$sudo vi  /etc/mysql/my.cnf

[mysqld_safe]

socket     = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

nice       = 0